# Wouldn't a relative of Naboth inherit his vineyard after he dies?

Tags: numbers, 1-kings

Numbers 27:8“Say to the Israelites, ‘If a man dies and leaves no son, give his inheritance to his daughter. 9If he has no daughter, give his inheritance to his brothers. 10If he has no brothers, give his inheritance to his father’s brothers. 11If his father had no brothers, give his inheritance to the nearest relative in his clan, that he may possess it. This is to have the force of law for the Israelites, as the Lord commanded Moses.’ ”

1 Kings 21:15When Jezebel heard that Naboth had been stoned to death, she said to Ahab, “Get up and take possession of the vineyard of Naboth the Jezreelite, who refused to give it to you for silver. For Naboth is no longer alive, but dead.”
16And when Ahab heard that Naboth was dead, he got up and went down to take possession of the vineyard of Naboth the Jezreelite.

Wouldn't a relative of Naboth inherit his vineyard even if they killed his sons?

Comment: Given the fact that most of the Israelites were out of Gods favor  it is safe to assume that if Naboth had an heir that would inherit Ahab would have no trouble getting that one to sell or trade the vineyard. Naboth was unique in his integrity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you think his relatives didn't know what happened?  Would you want be the relative to take possession and be the next in line to be stoned?  Stoning occurred in public.  His relatives would know that Naboth was stoned on false charges.

Jezebel was a Phoenician Baal worshiper.  She had no regard for the Law of Moses.  She tried to make Israel Baal worshipers.

> **JEZEBEL, WIFE OF AHAB, DAUGHTER OF ETHBAAL** (אִיזֶבֶל, izevel). Baal-worshiper who kills prophets of the Lord, threatens Elijah, and orders the murder of Naboth
> --
> Roden, C. (2016). Jezebel, Wife of Ahab, Daughter of Ethbaal. In J. D. Barry, D. Bomar, D. R. Brown, R. Klippenstein, D. Mangum, C. Sinclair Wolcott, … W. Widder (Eds.), The Lexham Bible Dictionary. Bellingham, WA: Lexham Press.

> **Worship of Baal**
> After marrying Jezebel, Ahab promotes the worship of Baal in Israel (1 Kgs 16:31–33).... Jezebel then threatens to kill **Elijah, who flees into the wilderness** (1 Kgs 19:2–4).
> --
> Roden, C. (2016). Jezebel, Wife of Ahab, Daughter of Ethbaal. In J. D. Barry, D. Bomar, D. R. Brown, R. Klippenstein, D. Mangum, C. Sinclair Wolcott, … W. Widder (Eds.), The Lexham Bible Dictionary. Bellingham, WA: Lexham Press.

> **Plot to Kill Naboth**
> Jezebel’s next appearance in the narrative comes after Ahab fails to acquire a vineyard from Naboth the Jezreelite. Seeking to ease her husband’s frustration, Jezebel engineers a scheme with the elders of Jezreel to have Naboth stoned to death on false charges. After Naboth is killed, Jezebel instructs Ahab to seize the vineyard (1 Kgs 21:1–16). As a result of the murder, Elijah pronounces Yahweh’s judgment on Ahab and declares that Jezebel will be eaten by dogs (1 Kgs 21:17–24; compare 2 Kgs 9:7–10).
> --
> Roden, C. (2016). Jezebel, Wife of Ahab, Daughter of Ethbaal. In J. D. Barry, D. Bomar, D. R. Brown, R. Klippenstein, D. Mangum, C. Sinclair Wolcott, … W. Widder (Eds.), The Lexham Bible Dictionary. Bellingham, WA: Lexham Press.

Comment: +1 Good one. I was wondering about how to answer it until I saw your answer. Even Elijah was scared of Jezebel.

Answer (score 0):

The [Talmud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talmud) addresses this problem in Tractate Sanhedrin, folio 48b. In short, it presents a dispute as to how the law of inheritance was understood. According to one opinion, the law you cite from Numbers is only applicable in a regular case of death; when, however, the death was a state execution the property would indeed go to the king rather than the next of kin. The other opinion maintains that the law in Numbers applies to state executions as well, but in fact in this situation Ahab *was* the next of kin:

> Our Rabbis taught: The property of those executed by the State belongs to the King: the property of those executed by the Beth din belongs to their heirs. R. Judah said: Even the property of those executed by the State goes to their heirs. Said they to R. Judah: But it is not written, Behold he [Ahab] is in the vineyard of Naboth whither he is gone down to take possession of it? — He answered: He [Naboth] was his [the King's] cousin, and therefore he [Ahab] was his legitimate heir. But he [Naboth] had many sons! — He [the King] slew both him and his sons, he replied, as it is written, Surely I have seen yesterday the blood of Naboth and the blood of his sons. And the Rabbis? — They refer to his potential sons.  Now, on the view that their property belongs to the King, it is correct: hence it is said, Naboth did curse God and the King.  But on the view that their estate belongs to their heirs, why mention and the King?  — But even according to your reasoning,  why state, 'God'?  Hence [it must have been added] in order to increase the anger [of the judges]. So here too, it [the mention of the King] was made in order to increase the anger [of the judges]. Now, on the view that the estate belongs to the King, it is correct: hence it is written, And Joab fled unto the tent of the Lord and caught hold of the horns of the Altar;  and it is further written, And he said Nay, but I will die here. But on the view that their estate belongs to their heirs, what difference did it make to him? — [It would serve] to prolong his life for a while.
>
> ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/sanhedrin/sanhedrin_48.html#PARTb))